# Terraform - issue with tags formating for Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have issue with tags, this pattern worked on AWS but for Azure i got error which is strange, can someone review and help? Thanks.

$ terraform plan

Error: azurerm_virtual_network.vnet: 1 error(s) occurred:

- azurerm_virtual_network.vnet: At column 5, line 2: merge: argument 1 should be type map, got type string in:

  ${
      merge(map("Name", var.env_name),
      var.global_tags,
      var.vnet_tags)}

  main.tf

  ```
  resource "azurerm_resource_group" "vnet" {
    name     = "${var.resource_group_name}"
    location = "${var.location}"
  }

  resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    name                = "${var.vnet_name}"
    location            = "${var.location}"
    address_space       = ["${var.address_space}"]
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.vnet.name}"
    dns_servers         = "${var.dns_servers}"

  tags = "${
      merge(map("Name", format("%s %s", var.env_name, "Vnet")), 
      var.global_tags, 
      var.vnet_tags)}"
  ```

  variables.tf

  ```
  variable "env_name" {
       default = "Company DTAP"
  }

  variable "global_tags" {
    default = "Company Ltd"
  }
  variable "vnet_tags" {
    default = "Production"
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont really know what you are trying to achieve, but `merge` works with [maps](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#merge-map1-map2-), where as in your case `global_tags` and `vnet_tags` are strings. and the error says just that

so you cast your first input to the `merge` function to MAP, but dont cast the other ones. you should cast them to MAP as well.

Comment: thanks, this worked>

tags = "${
    merge(map("Name", format("%s %s", var.env_name, "Vnet")),
    map(var.global_tags,
    var.vnet_tags))}"
}